# How to substitute character in string using regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to change the following string

```
^mylog\.20151204\-\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\.gc\.log\.gz$
```

to this:

```
^mylog\.2015-12-04\-\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\.gc\.log\.gz$
```

(`20151204` changed to `2015-12-04` only)

I can accomplish it by:

```
re.sub("20151204", "2015-12-04", string)
```

where

```
string= ^mylog\.20151204\-\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\.gc\.log\.gz$
```

But the value `20151204` is a date and will change and I can't have it hardcoded.

I tried:

```
re.sub("2015\\d{2}\\d{2}", "2015\-\\d{2}\-\\d{2}", string)
```

However this did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use capture groups in the pattern and backreferences in the replacement:

```
result = re.sub("2015(\\d{2})(\\d{2})", "2015-\\1-\\2", string)
                     ^      ^^      ^         ^^^ ^^^   
// => ^mylog\.2015-12-04\-\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\.gc\.log\.gz$
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/8Gyv8Y)

If you need to match any year after `^mylog\.`, you can use

```
result = re.sub(r"^\^mylog\\\.(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})", r"^mylog\.\1-\2-\3", string)
```

See [another demo](http://ideone.com/a43CDC)

Answer (score 0):

You first need to find the date and then convert it into the required format and then replace the new string in your old text.

See the code below:

```
 text = "^mylog\.20151204\-\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\.gc\.log\.gz$"
 search = re.search(r'\d{4}\d{2}\d{2}',text)
 search = search.group()
```

you get `search` as:

> > 20151204

Now create the date as you want:

```
 new_text = search[0:4] + "-" + search[4:6] + "-" + search[6:8]
```

So `new_text` will be:

> > 2015-12-04

Now substitute this `new_text` in place of the earlier string using `re.sub()

```
  text = re.sub(search,new_text,text)
```

So now `text` will be:

> > ^mylog\.2015-12-04\-\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\.gc\.log\.gz$